# NodeJS, Express - Render EJS view to a download file

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a NodeJS, Express 3 app that uses EJS templating. I have a route that enables 'preview' of some form fields containing HTML and CSS that are posted. It simply plugs them in and renders my `preview.ejs` template like this..

```
app.post('/preview', function(req, res){

    var htm = req.body.htm;
    var css = req.body.css;

    res.render('preview',{_layoutFile:'', htm:htm, css:css});
});
```

What I'd like to do now is a similar route that forces download of the file instead..

```
app.post('/download', function(req, res){

    var htm = req.body.htm;
    var css = req.body.css;

    // res.download or res.sendfile here ??
});
```

I see that there is a `res.sendfile()` and `res.download()`, but how can I use these with my EJS 'preview' view template?

P.S. - I'm also using Mikeal's `request` is this same app. I wonder if there is a way I could use pipe to fs (filesystem) and then force download of the saved file?

Comment: You should be able to pipe the response from `request` directly to the Express response object: `res.attachment(); request(...).pipe(res);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.attachment

`res.attachment()` sets `Content-Disposition: attachment` header which tells the browser to treat the response as a download.

```
app.post('/download', function(req, res){

    var htm = req.body.htm;
    var css = req.body.css;

    res.attachment();
    res.render('preview',{_layoutFile:'', htm:htm, css:css});
});
```